# Unable to run Heroku app (Flask) locally

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am unable to deploy a Heroku app locally, however it does work remotely.

This is the error I am receiving.

```
web.1  | [2015-12-31 18:07:47 -0400] [4179] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.3
web.1  | [2015-12-31 18:07:47 -0400] [4179] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (4179)
web.1  | [2015-12-31 18:07:47 -0400] [4179] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web.1  | [2015-12-31 18:07:47 -0400] [4183] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4183
web.1  | [2015-12-31 18:07:47 -0400] [4183] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
web.1  | le>
web.1  | "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
web.1  | [2015-12-31 18:07:47 -0400] [4183] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4183)
web.1  | [2015-12-31 18:07:47 -0400] [4179] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
web.1  | [2015-12-31 18:07:47 -0400] [4179] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: What do you mean by deploy it locally?

Comment: Is there any issue when you want to run the app with app.run()?

Comment: When I mean to deploy locally, I mean using the command `heroku local`, and to answer itmard's question, I am able to run it using app.run().